# How to replace fql in v2.2 for this request?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

How can I retrieve fan page's comments  with graph api v2.2 ?

Actually, I use FQL to retrieve comments of the posts lastly updated in a page since a date. For that I use update_date in the reques's filter.

Fql will be obsolete in V2.2. How can i substitute this with graph api ?

THank you very much for your help.

Reda.

Comment: You can’t. API v2 does not offer all the functionality FQL offered, especially when it comes to filtering results. You should probably look into real-time updates, so that Facebook notifies your app when something changes.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much for your answer. Real-time updates does not match my needs. I have tested it a few months ago. I hope Facebook API team have made some changes to feet my problem :).